# Creating ELF instead of a.out

Tags: c, gcc, elf

I need to generate a simple "Hello World" ELF32 executable using `gcc`.

I don't seem to have the `gcc-elf` command though.

Is it possible to create ELF binaries instead of `a.out` without building `gcc` again?

I'm assuming it should be possible with some options, but am unsure how to proceed.

Comment: A quick look at the man for gcc points at the -melf option.. But Im guessing it'll be different depending on which architecture you are targeting..

Comment: What is your target platform?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`a.out` is very old, we're talking kernel version 1.2 of linux.  Assuming you are operating on any remotely recent linux platform, you are generating elf executables by default.  Use the `file` command on the output executable to verify.  E.g.:

```
$ file server
server: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.15, not stripped
```

Answer (score 12):

Check the file `a.out`:

```bash
$ file a.out
a.out: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), for GNU/Linux 2.6.9, dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.9, not stripped
```

I believe the default name is retained as `a.out` but the format is ELF.

Comment: `a.out` is the required standard compiler/linker output name, and was the default output name long before anyone ever spoke of "a.out file format". It's an unfortunate accident that the name ended up being ambiguous like this...

Comment: The name stands for "assembler output".