# How do I create ELF executables?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, elf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Creating ELF instead of a.out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5565594/creating-elf-instead-of-a-out)

When I use the command `gcc hello.cpp`, I end up with `a.out`.

I read somewhere that `a.out` files are different from ELF executables.

How do I instruct `gcc` to create ELF executable?

Comment: you can vote to close your own question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In fact, `gcc` uses the name `a.out` for historical reasons.  You're actuall getting an `ELF` executable.  You can verify this with the `file` command, which will give you output along the lines of:

```
$ file a.out
a.out: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, not stripped
```

Answer (score 5):

gcc uses the name a.out as the default executable name for historical reasons. If you run "file a.out" you'll see that it's actually an ELF file.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to see the name `a.out`, then use the `-o` switch to change the output filename:

```
g++ -o hello hello.cpp
```

Note also that while `gcc` often works for C++ programs, you should use `g++` instead.