# How can I generate an ELF file with GCC?

Tags: gcc, compilation, executable, elf, file-format

I am writing C and C++ code on Linux OS and I am using GCC.

After finishing my code, I would like to generate an ELF file. I just can generate `a.out` file and I don't need it.

How can I get an ELF file? What generates the ELF file?

Comment: The a.out is an ELF file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating ELF instead of a.out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5565594/creating-elf-instead-of-a-out)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The compiler (i.e. `gcc` or `g++`) will invoke the linker (`ld`) which produces an ELF executable.

In practice, you will use a builder program (like `make`) to drive `gcc` commands. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20146082/841108).

The default output file for `gcc` is still named `a.out` (for historical reasons) but is an ELF file. And you really want to ask `gcc` to output an executable with a more fancy name.

Simple example, you code a single-file `hello-world.c` program. You can compile it with e.g.

```bash
gcc -Wall -g hello-world.c -o hello-world-bin
```

<sup>(order of arguments to `gcc` matters a lot!)</sup>

And the produced `hello-world-bin` is an [ELF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) executable. Check with:

```bash
file hello-world-bin
```

Then run it with:

```bash
./hello-world-bin your arguments to it
```

Later, learn how to use the `gdb` debugger on it.

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20146082/841108) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7937638/841108) answers.

Comment: Very descriptive and useful comments. I understood very well.